# Creating an app with four independent sections, where each section has its own routes and state

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Asking this here because of an [issue that was closed](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/7889) because the maintainer believes this is already a supported use-case of react-router.

My app has four sections that can be switched between by using a sidebar on the left. All sections are rendered at all times, and only one is displayed at a time using a custom screen switcher component. This is also so that state is not lost for sections you have visited.

However, I'm having issues using a singular router for this. When I switch to a different section, the one I was just at loses all its state because it sees I'm at a completely different URL now, so it forgets all the data it's loaded and has to re-load the next time I visit it. (I'm not using a `Switch` for rendering the sections, since that unmounts them if the route doesn't match. The `Switch`es *inside* the section do de-activate, though.)

Ideally, when I switch away from a section, that section should remember its path and I just activate another section's router. When switching back, I can re-activate the router and the full path appears in the browser address bar, just as the user left it.

There's a high probability that this use case is *not* supported by react-router. But in case there is, how would I go about it? Do I really need multiple routers or is there something else I can use?

Answer (score 0):

The maintainer got back to me and clarified that this is [definitely already possible](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/7891#issuecomment-871041377). I would use a plain [`<Router>`](https://reactrouter.com/core/api/Router) component and pass a custom [history](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/) that would only update/listen to browser history changes conditionally.

Edit: I've since successfully implemented this, and it works really well. I can't share any code unfortunately.